# Monthly Folders with PS script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that after the user inputs a year, filepath, and dayoftheweek. Will create one folder each month for a year on the first day in the month that was specified. So if the user puts in "Wednesday" it will find the date of the first Wednesday in each month and create the folder.

Input example would be:

```
New-DayOfWeekFolders -parentPath c:\temp -year 2017  -dayOfWeek wednesday
```

i know there is plenty wrong with it (I'm terrible with scripting) but here is what I have right now:

```
function NewMonthlyFolder{

    param(
    [string] $ParentPath,
    [string] $Year, 
    [string] $DayOfWeek
)

$start = Get-Date $Year
$end = Get-Date
    $day = [enum]::Parse([type]"System.DayOfWeek", $DayOfWeek)

    While($start.DayOfWeek -ne $day) 
    {
        $start = $start.AddDays(1)
    }
    Do
    {
        $folderName = $start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        New-Item -Path $ParentPath -Name $folderName -ItemType directory
        $start = $start.AddMonths(1)).AddDays(-1)
    } While($start -le $end)
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you having a specific issue? Error messages?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
[string] $ParentPath="C:\temp"
[string] $Year="2005" 
[string] $DayOfWeek="lundi"


$LowerDayOfWeek=$DayOfWeek.ToLower()

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 13; $i++)
{ 
   $start = get-date -Year $Year -Month $i -Day 1

   for ($j = 0; $j -lt 7; $j++)
   {
       $currentdate=$start.AddDays($j)

       if ($currentdate.ToString("dddd") -eq $LowerDayOfWeek)
       {
           New-Item -ItemType Directory -path "$ParentPath\$($currentdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" -Force
           break
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
[string] $ParentPath="C:\temp"
[string] $Year="2017" 
[string] $DayOfWeek="monday"

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 13; $i++)
{ 
   $start = get-date -Year $Year -Month $i -Day 1
   $daysToFirstCorrectDay = (([Int] [DayOfWeek] $DayOfWeek) - [Int]$start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
   $NewParth=$start.AddDays($daysToFirstCorrectDay).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -path "$ParentPath\$NewParth" -Force -WhatIf
}
```